# How to parse a xml feed using feed parser python?

Tags: python, xml, rss, feedparser

Im trying to parse a feed in python using feedparser. But all I get is `None` returned. Im not sure what im missing. Here is my code:

```
import feedparser

def rss(self):
    rss = 'https://news.google.com/news?q=fashion&output=rss'
    feed = feedparser.parse(rss)
    for key in feed.entries: 
        return key.title
```

If you think there is a better rss/xml feed parse. Please let me know. (Im new to python)

`print(key)` displays `none`
and `print(len(feed.entries))` also displays `none`

```
print(feed)
{'feed': {}, 'entries': [], 'bozo': 1, 'bozo_exception': URLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)'),)}

print(feedparser)
<module 'feedparser' from '/Users/User_name/python-projects/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py'>
```

Comment: You're returning after just one iteration of the loop. Why not return all the `key`s' titles using a list or a tuple?

Comment: Hi Sam, Even if I do print(key.title) instead of return. It still results in none

Comment: @stovfl. I updated the question accordingly

Comment: @stovfl updated to include results of print(feed) and print(feedparser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue was actually with the SSL handshake fixed it by adding `ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`.

For anyone else facing the issue. Full code is:

```
import feedparser
import ssl
if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
rss = 'https://news.google.com/news?q=fashion&output=rss'
feed = feedparser.parse(rss)

print(feed)
```

Comment: Doing so, will allow anyone with a privileged network position is able to trivially execute a man in the middle attack against a Python application using either of these HTTP clients, and change traffic at will. [Enabling certificate verification by default for stdlib http clients](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/)

Comment: @stovfl oh right. Would it be better to use `create_default_context` instead of `_create_unverified_context`?

Comment: Neither the first nor the second. I would go to install Certificates using `pip install urllib3[secure]`, read about [Section: Certificate verification](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html?highlight=certificate)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following basic code, which works fine for me and gave me 10 items in the feed when I ran it.

1. Install [feedparser](https://pypi.org/project/feedparser/) from pip

```
pip install feedparser
```

2. Usage

```py
import urllib2
import feedparser

url = "https://news.google.com/news?q=fashion&output=rss"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

print response

d = feedparser.parse(response)
print len(d.entries)
for item in d.entries:
    print "------"
    print item.title
    if 'subtitle' in item:
        print item.subtitle
    print item.link
    print item.description
    print item.published
    print item.id
    print item.updated
    if 'content' in item:
        print item.content
```

Or, paste the FULL code you're running, and I'll take a look.

Comment: @kevinabraham I think that means you're simply unable to read data from the feed, it's not a Python coding issue. Do you see data if you try that URL direct from a web browser?

Comment: Yes I can. When I go directly in the link it shows text `<rss version="2.0"><channel><generator>NFE/1.0</generator><title>fashion - Google News</title>`......